# Programmatically created textfields will not save text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

**SITUATION:**

My two textfields are being declared in my .h file:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
UITextField *countTotalFieldUniversal;
UITextField *flavorNameUniversal;
}
```

And instantiated in my .m file:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   // Label default cell
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if(cell==nil){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   }

   //Text fields used for editing
   countTotalFieldUniversal = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 85, 30)];
   countTotalFieldUniversal. delegate = self;
   flavorNameUniversal = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 280, 30)];
   flavorNameUniversal.delegate = self;

   flavorNameUniversal.text = @"Flavor";
   countTotalFieldUniversal.text = @"Count";
```

**ATTEMPTS TO DEBUG:**

When I try to print the current textfield value in setEditing using this code:

```
NSString *flavorText = ((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1]).text;
NSString *countText = ((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:2]).text;
NSLog(@"newFlavorName: %@", flavorText);
NSLog(@"newCountTotal: %@", countText);
```

I only get the unedited, original labels: "Flavor" and "Count".

When I try to print the current textfield values in setEditing using this code:

```
NSString * newFlavorName = flavorNameUniversal.text;
NSString * newCountTotal = countTotalFieldUniversal.text;
NSLog(@"newFlavorName: %@", newFlavorName);
NSLog(@"newCountTotal: %@", newCountTotal);
```

I get null values for both!

**It's like my changes to the text field aren't tracked at all!**

Comment: You're also creating new text fields each time a row is (re)loaded on the table view. Or requesting the text fields on any specific cell.

Comment: Where are you setting the tag on the text fields?

Comment: I'm setting the tags in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Wain - wow, thanks. I didn't even notice. I moved the initwithframe and delegation of both textfields to ViewDidLoad. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your changes for the text field AREN'T being tracked at all!  At least they are being tracked and then released before you get your hands on them.

Don't instantiate a new `UITextField` object every time.  I suggest you subclass UITableViewCell to handle ownership and drawing of the two `UITextField`'s.  Give your subclass a two text field properties (`@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField1/2`) and make sure to instantiate them either in `init` or use lazy instantiation in the setter.

Use delegation (the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method declared in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol) to get the data from your `UITextField` to your viewController.

That SHOULD work and track the changes made to the text field.